# Firebase Crashlytics: dSYMS is not processed correctly

Tags: firebase

I have a problem with Firebase Crashlytics, my uploaded dSYMs are not processed.

I see a missing required dSYMs warning, and although I uploaded it via Firebase Crashlytics tool (I downloaded the dSYMs directly on Itunes Connect), it seems that my dSYMs are never processed.

I still getting the warning with missing required dSYMs, after waiting for hours.

I retried many times without any luck. Could you please help?

Here is how I uploaded my dSYMs from terminal:

```
➜  Crashlytics.framework ./upload-symbols -gsp GoogleService-Info.plist -p ios appDsyms.zip
Successfully submitted symbols for architecture armv7 with UUID 031dea93b9943ccda1e7b8cb31513e3d in dSYM: /var/folders/9m/lr5qwb653hbf5k33rlg4288r0000gp/T//appDsyms.zip.unzipped/031dea93-b994-3ccd-a1e7-b8cb31513e3d.dSYM
Successfully submitted symbols for architecture arm64 with UUID 39e5a25fd6da3945bb7ed60795c4883d in dSYM: /var/folders/9m/lr5qwb653hbf5k33rlg4288r0000gp/T//appDsyms.zip.unzipped/39e5a25f-d6da-3945-bb7e-d60795c4883d.dSYM
Successfully uploaded Crashlytics symbols
```

I still getting warning of missing the dSYM with Id 39e5a25fd6da3945bb7ed60795c4883d on Firebase Crashlytics report:

[Missing required dSYMs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nrm7N.png)

This is the first time I see this problem, my previous dSYMs always processed correctly.

Thank you.

Comment: It happens the same to me, I've uploaded a version yesterday and I can't upload the dsyms to Firebase, However I could do it in previous versions. Let us know if you fix it! :)

Comment: This is happening to me as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a failure in the API of Crashlytics :). This morning all the dsyms were processed fine. It happened to more people as well but it is fixed.

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/5327

Comment: This issue came back again with my new update :(
Hope my dSYMs will be processed.

Comment: :( If it happens to me again I wont waste so much time as the last day hahaha, However my optional dsyms never got processed, I hope they fix the whole Crashlytics soon :(